# Storing a Hash of IDs in a database field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Here's what I could use your help with.

In my app, I need to create AttachmentTemps (temporary attachments that go to S3)
I create these attachmenttemp (0 to 100) possible, in the controller.

What I want to do is somehow store the attachmentTemp IDs in the a separate model IncomingMail.

Then later, when delayed_job access incoming mail to do all the image processing etc, I want to use the attachmenttemp ids (if any) to get the @attachmenttemp record, and do some process on it.

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Or maybe I shouldn't store the AttachmentTemp Ids but rather the actual @attachment temp object? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommending having a model like this:

AttachmentTemp (id, incoming_mail_id, ....)
IncomingMail (id, ....)

Instead of storing the attachment ids as a hash, simply store the incoming_mail_id on the attachment_temps table, that way when you are processing an IncomingMail object you can simply query the attachment_temps table for all the related objects using the incoming_mail_id.

Comment: smart people rule. I love how you suggested a beter way to solve the problem. Thanks